# How to pass an Array from a Class to a JSP File

Tags: java, arrays, servlets

This is where I create my Array:

```
   public class Main {
public void main() {
    String[] CartaV={"A","K","Q","J","T","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2"};
    String[] CartaP={"S","H","C","D"};
    String[] m = new String[7];
    Random rand1 = new Random();
    Random rand2 = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        m[i]=CartaV[rand1.nextInt(13)];
        m[i]=m[i]+CartaP[rand2.nextInt(4)];
    }


    //System.out.println(mc.mejorJugada(m));
}

}
```

And here I got my JSP File, as you can see, I'm importing the class, but still can't find a way to print the Array:

```
    <%@page import="bootcamp.e003.dos.Main"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Mano7</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        //I want to print on screen my array
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            out.println(m[i]);
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: @GriffeyDog, while I agree with your link above, I think that OP is just trying to poke JSP a little bit, judging by the program's intent and the package name (bootcamp), maybe it's best to leave the semantics of the intricacies of conventions until they've dived deeper into the servlet stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're not invoking your `main()` method in the `Main` class.

Also you're not returning any value or using any means of sharing variables.

What you could do is change the signature to something like this:

```
public String[] main() {
 // Code here
  return m;
}
```

Then in your `jsp` invoke the method like this:

```
<%
    String m[] = (new Main()).main();
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        out.println(m[i]);
    }
%>
```

Comment: Thank you! now I realized what I did.

Comment: @JavierHeisecke You can upvote / accept if you feel this is the correct answer

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, I just checked

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using [Request Attributes](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))!

First, set your Attribute in your Servlet class, like so:

```
request.setAttribute("testing","testvalue"); //Pass your array here
```

Then in your view JSP file, you can access it like this:

```
String testValue = (String) request.getAttribute("testing");

if(testValue != null) {
   System.out.println("Test Value.... "+testValue);
}
```